# How to fetch data for a reusable layout component in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I need to put slugs in my Header component which is reusable in all the site inside the layout:

```
const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />//////////this one.
      {children}
      <Footer />
     </>
  );
};
```

My slugs goings from the server side and I need to dynamically fetch them only one time in the header.

Inside the header something like:

```
categoriesLinks.map(category=> {
  return <div>{category.SLUG}</div>
})
```

But because it's a reusable component I don't know how and where to invoke the `getServerSideProps` or `getStaticProps`.

- if I use the index component for example I need to fetch data in every component
- if I tried to fetch it inside `getInitialProps` in the `_app`, it doesn't get it (get `undefined`)

What is the right way to handle this? It seems like a really big issue and I couldn't find the right solution for this.

Comment: Could you add the code in your `_app` with your attempt to fetch the data in `getInitialProps`?

Answer (score 3):

You can't call getServerSideProps or getStaticProps in a component. You have to write the getServersideprops or getStaticProps inside the page and then pass the fetched data to the layout. You can also use a state management system like react context or recoil (recommended) to save the data so you won't have to re-fetch every time and then in the layout do the following

```
useEffect(() => ChangeData(data), [])
```

This code will render your data once. ChangeData is the stateChanger for recoil or react context.

Comment: what about a component that is shared in the _app? for example, if you have footer component that fetches data from CMS, but you want to statically generate all pages using it.

Comment: @sergioviniciuss any solutions for this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

Update October 2023. Im in the same issue. After much time research, the solution is only fetching data in _app.tsx, use useEffect() and function get data. Where render layout components and pass to the layout component contain header component, then pass data to child component you need. Absolutely use redux or something like that but this time im just want to do that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please be sure to either convert this post into a comment when you get commenting privilege, or to turn it into a qualified answer (see [answer] for guidance)

Answer (score -1):

This is what I found on Vercel https://nextjs.org/blog/layouts-rfc#data-fetching-in-layouts via an ongoing discussion on https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/10949

---

**You can fetch data in a layout.js file by using the Next.js data fetching methods getStaticProps or getServerSideProps.**

**For example, a blog layout could use getStaticProps to fetch categories from a CMS, which can be used to populate a sidebar component:**

// app/blog/layout.js

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const categories = await getCategoriesFromCMS();

  return {
    props: { categories },
  };
}

export default function BlogLayout({ categories, children }) {
  return (
    <>
      <BlogSidebar categories={categories} />
      {children}
    </>
  );
}
```

To see

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, the OP doesnt want the static data somewhere in his /pages/ layout component, but in his app layout component